# Twitter integration in Blackberry Application and Twitter api

Tags: api, blackberry, twitter, for-loop

I'm trying to integrate twitter to my blackberry application and i've downloaded twitter4j api but i doesn't seem to work out because eclipse doesn't support some of the classes which api have.If u've any idea as to how do i go abt that please reply.

Comment: could u please tell me from where u downloaded it?

Comment: Hello Swati, i've downloaded from this link http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html. Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: Hey Shweta thank u fr the link even i am trying to do twitter integration but couldnt find a way to do that

Comment: Hi Shweta and Swati whether you implemented Twitter integration with Blackberry? I need your help

Answer (score 2):

I have done Twitter integration in BlackBerry.

And I have post entire source code on the blackberry support fourm.

You all can get code from there

I am using twitter_api_me-1.8.jar for twitter integration.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Twitter-is-Integrated-in-BlackBerry/m-p/1698157

Pawan Jha
Thanks

Comment: Great guide... u saved a life, thanks a million... I feel like clicking up 10times but i am entitled to only 1.. Cheers! sent you a mail btw, please check your box..

Comment: Any idea About twitter integration in BB 10

Comment: Currently not working can anybody help me for new twitter API.