# Twitter Api with OS6.0 in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter API with BlackBerry OS 6.0.
Is there any difference between OS 6.0 and 5.0 when using the Twitter API?

I have the consumer key and secret key.

Comment: Got any specific question? Code exemple? Thing you have tried? And try to write better english, "coz","y" and "b" are not english word. And since english is not my first language reading thing like this is making it harder to understand your question.

Comment: Some context on the twitter API would be helpful.  Are you talking about a REST API, or some jar file that they distribute?  Are you writing Java code, or is this a webworks project?

Comment: I answered something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252867/integrate-twitter-in-a-blackberry-application/12882106#12882106) and a similar question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647359/twitter-integration-in-blackberry-application-and-twitter-api?rq=1) as well.. Cheers!